# Select2-Not converting my select

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to use the Select2 JQuery control and can't get it to work with a select on my form.

This select is defined like this:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        name="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[3].ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID" 
        id="QuestionBasicSection.Questions[3].ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID" 
        multiple>
    <of course I have several options here>
</select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#QuestionBasicSection.Questions[3].ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID").select2();
    });
</script>
```

But the select2 is not being converted nor showing and I can't determine why.
Could it have something to do with the id of the `<select>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the selector, #QuestionBasicSection.Questions[3].ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID is not a valid selector due to the dots and brackets, you can scape those characters this way:

```
$("#QuestionBasicSection\\.Questions\\[3\\]\\.ANSWER_LOOKUP_OPTION_ID").select2();
```